# total word taken form search box and send ajax cal with total word

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

i have problem with search functionaility with ajax call and php.here my problem is searching character by character using keyup function.its taking some little bit itme. i want total word searching.please any body help to me how to take total word and send ajax cal with total word not single character

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

use the blur-Eventhandler instead of the keyUp Eventhandler. That way your Event will only be triggered if the user leaves the inputfield with which he's trying to search.

So instead of:

```
$("selector").keyUp(function(e) {  your ajaxCode; }
```

Try:

```
$("selector").blur(function(e) { your ajax Code; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `change`

$('#selecter').change(function(){

```
    var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "some.php",
     data: {value=val},
     success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
       }
    });    
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/